# RGB light acting weird

Tags: power-supply, fan, rgb, molex

I added 2 fans through molex connections (0.18 Amps each) and now the side panel case RGB does not automatically go on anymore when I start up my PC, even after disconnecting the new fans.

The RGB is connected to the front panel and gets power from a molex, it's not connected to the motherboard (it's part of the PC case).

The weird part is that it does light up when I press the dedicated LED button on the front panel (used for cycling through the colors) but it's not "remembering" to stay on after shutting down and booting the PC again.

What is the cause here and why doesn't it still work after disconnecting the fans?

Comment: How are/were the fans connected? Are they perhaps connected between the +12V and +5V lines by way of a “speed lowering“ adapter?

Comment: From what you've said, I'd be surprised if the 2 fans are/were related to your issue... sounds to me like somethings, somehow, gone bung with your RGB thingy (could be as simple ss a loose connection, or bad as a faulty 'front panel' controller). Make/Model of your case/rgb light setup might be helpful.

Comment: @DanielB I'm not sure what you're talking about. The 2 new fans are connected in 
 a chain of 2 molexes which are parallel to a chain of 5 molexes (4 of these are fans and 1 is the power for the concerning LED). There is no speed lowering adapter.

Comment: @user1138 I have an Azza Taurus 5000. I have disconnected and reconnected all the cables to make sure. The side panel RGB consists of 3 LED lights, each light has a wire that is connected to the front panel via 3 separate cables (see picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/ir7mu5idc1gtnuo/LED%20cables.jpg?raw=1). There is also a cable from the front panel connected to a molex connector. I have tried different molex connectors but no avail.

Comment: A quick google and it would seem your problem is in fact a "feature"' - "By default the RGB LEDs on the side panel are not turned on. To turn them on just press the button on the top of the case, this button will also cycle through the different colors as well. Oddly enough once the LEDs are on you cannot turn them off unless you power down your system. You can cycle through white, blue, yellow, red, green, orange, and purple colors. There is also a breathing a pulse mode, both of which will continually switch colors as they go through their actions."

Comment: Source of the quote - https://thinkcomputers.org/azza-taurus-5000-case-review/4/    I imagined a controller with some smarts, but it sounds like it uses a pretty simple switch setup. I'd suggest checking your manual and confirming with Azza how its supposed to work.

Comment: @user1138 Thanks! I have indeed read that review claiming what you've said but I'm positive mine lit up automatically when I booted the PC. Unfortunately, Azza does not have these cases anymore to test it out and they can't remember how it's supposed to work. 
Is it possible that adding the 2 fans permanently redirected the power away from the LED even after disconnecting the fans? 
Is it also possible the RGB used a bit of power from the mobo in order to turn on at boot even if it's connected to a molex? (note: the front panel headers to the mobo does not contain a dedicated RGB LED header)

Comment: I don't know the circuitry involved and the only mention of all the bling-bling bits in the manual is the "Power Led" button. Logically; 1. There's no need for the mobo to be involved here, 2. There's no such thing as 'redirecting power' - if something is connected to the PSU, it's gettin powered... so 3. The likely case is that, On-Cycle colours-Off is how it's supposed to work. And Azza's fobbing you off... they would use the exact same system in a current case and should be able to tell you how it works... maybe ask on an Azza/Gaming related forum (if it exists).

Comment: @user1138 Thanks a lot for your help and info. I will ask around.

Comment: NP man, good luck! :-)

Comment: @user1138 So I've asked around. All users with the same issue had their LED cables disconnected before connecting them to test it out for me. One of them claimed the RGB LED _sometimes_ lights up automatically when booting the PC but not always. The only one who didn't have this issue never had the LED cables disconnected. I myself disconnected the cables to install the fans. 

What might your conclusion be when reading this? Could disconnecting the LED cables and using the PC without it really be the cause here? I can't imagine we're all having a faulty PSU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final verdict - poorly designed and/or cheaply manufactured electronics within the RGB LED circuit are failing and/or not functioning as intended. OR you (and evidently some others) are mistaken as to the functioning of this RGB LED system. Either way, beyond repairing/modifying/replacing that circuitry yourself (a tall order without specific tools/knowledge), or buying a whole new RGB LED system that is advertised to function as you desire, I think you are stuck with what you've got.

Your (and everybody elses) PSU is fine and functioning as intended - delivering volts/amps. And your motherboard also has nothing to do with it.

The RGB LED system/circuitry itself is entirely the problem!

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed explanation!

Comment: "Thumbs up" :-)